# Change Layout Direction (ltr to rtl, rtl to ltr) in blazor wasm based on selected culture

Tags: c#, blazor, single-page-application, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I have a blazor wasm application running on .NET 6 which supports localization but I am unable to find a way to change the direction of layout based on selected culture. I was trying to detect the direction of selected culture and change the `dir` of `html` tag but the issue is that the main layout code is in `index.html` file which doesn't support razor syntax.

Any idea on resolving the issue?

Comment: It is the default structure of Blazor Web Assembly and if we change the `index.html` to `index.razor` the project breaks since script tag is not allowed in razor components.

Comment: Use JSInterop `InvokeVoid("document.body.setAttribute","dir","rtl")`

Comment: You will probably need to do a lot more than that to make it nice though.

Comment: Changing the layout must be based on C# condition, C# code is not working in . html file

Comment: C# code works in Blazor - how are you checking the culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been waiting for Blazor Repl to come back from the dead...

This is how you can change it from C#

```html
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Change Direction</h1>
<button @onclick=SetRTL>
    RTL
</button>
<button @onclick=SetLTR>
    LTR
</button>
```

```cs
@code
{
    void SetDIR(string direction)
    {
        if (JS is IJSInProcessRuntime sr)
            sr.InvokeVoid("document.body.setAttribute","dir",direction);
        else
            JS.InvokeVoidAsync("document.body.setAttribute","dir",direction);
    }
    void SetRTL() => SetDIR("rtl");
    void SetLTR() => SetDIR("ltr");
}
```

Demo: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wQaJQrPT36Da5Urf52